# Use tf.Keras with Tensorflow optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use tf.keras with the new AdamW optimizer in tensorflow and am running into issues. A toy version of the code is as follows:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.opt import AdamWOptimizer
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import TFOptimizer

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, activation="tanh", input_shape=(3,)))

tfopt = AdamWOptimizer(weight_decay=0.1, learning_rate=.004)
optimizer = TFOptimizer(tfopt)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(np.random.random((5, 3)),
          np.random.random((5, 2)),
          epochs=5, batch_size=5)
```

Error is as follows:

```
../python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1605: in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
../python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py:153: in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins)
../python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:2978: in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
../python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py:1399: in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status object at 0x11ecde550>
type_arg = None, value_arg = None, traceback_arg = None

    def __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg):
      try:
        if c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status) != 0:
          raise _make_specific_exception(
              None, None,
              compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
>             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
E             tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value training/TFOptimizer/beta2_power
E                [[{{node training/TFOptimizer/beta2_power/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/TFOptimizer/AdamW/Assign"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](training/TFOptimizer/beta2_power)]]

../python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py:526: FailedPreconditionError
```

Comment: From which module do you import `AdamWOptimizer` and `TFOptimizer`?

Comment: Just updated the code to show that.

Comment: Does it work if you try to use a standard optimizer?

Comment: Could you please add the other imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `TFOptimizer` won't work in python 3.6 but it does work in 2.7.

However, you don't actually need to use TFOptimizer. Plugging the tensorflow optimizer `AdamWOptimizer` directly into the optimizer argument of fit runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this runs, and converges very fast to high accuracy for most of my classification goals, but there is one problem: the margins are very small, with all scores being close to 0.5. In addition, one classifier does not converge. With Adam, the results are better.